# regex to escape a part of string

Tags: python

I am new to python and I need to remove 'Rs.' from 'Rs. 150.00'.But if I remove '.' it removes dot from numeric digits also. Following is my code:

```
price = re.sub('/[^0-9_.]\Rs.\/', '','Rs. 150.00')
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you simply do string replacement:

```
>>>'Rs. 150.00'.replace('Rs.', '').strip()
'150.00'
```

Provided that you have more details in the string:

```
>>> re.search(r'\d+\.\d+', 'hello Rs. 150.00').group()
'150.00'

>>> re.search(r'\d+\.\d+', 'hello Rs. 150.00 and some more text').group()
'150.00'
```

This regular expression doesn't replace but finds a match for the digits.

Comment: Yes i can do but this a part of scraping code, so i need to pick only numeric characters only as some other string might be present.

Comment: So could you show the complete text where you need to do this and what is the output you expect from that text.

Comment: here i mean string = 'hello Rs. 150.00', if I use your code it would just remove Rs. only and extra strings are possible and may vary site to site.

Comment: Thanks it worked for current case and i hope it will work for all cases.

Comment: If it doesn't please post more example and I would be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Just like that it should work without grab the . between your number.

```
/Rs./
```

You can check that [example](http://regexr.com/3d99d)